# converge and converge absolutely of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$f(x)$ is a continuos fuction in $[0, 1]$ and differentiable twice on $0$.

$U_n=(-1)^{n}f(\frac{1}{n})$.
I need to prove that:

$1.$if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ converge then $f(0)=0$.

$2.$if $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty U_n$ converge absolutely.

Now, from the detail that $f(x)$ is differentiable twice on $0$ I think I need to write $f(1/n)$ with Maclaurin series with 2 degree but it doesn't work very nice. can you guide me please? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ [must necessarily satisfy $a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand). In your case, $a_n = (-1)^n f(\frac{1}{n})$ and $f$ is continuous; therefore...
2. If $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, you have, as you suggested,
   $$
   f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x+ \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + o(x^2) = \frac{f''(0)}{2}x^2 + o(x^2)
   $$
   when $x\to 0$, so in particular
   $$
   f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{f''(0)}{2n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)
   $$
   when $n\to\infty$. This implies $\lvert U_n\rvert = \frac{\lvert f''(0)\rvert}{2n^2} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$, and you can conclude by [theorem of comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_comparison_test):

   > If $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ are two non-negative sequences such that
   >   $a_n = b_n + o(b_n)$ (when $n\to\infty$), then $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ have same nature (i.e., they are either both convergent or both convergent).

Comment: understood!!! thanks!!